# Issue deleting a file in remote path via ssh

Tags: bash, ssh, cmd, del

I'm trying to delete a file on a remote path via ssh, the command I'm trying to use from my local computer is using bash and my remote computer uses cmd.

I'm trying to use the following command:

```
ssh user@host "del -f F:\\some\\path\\in\\remote\\1.computer\\1.filename.txt"
```

and in the logs I get the following error:
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Any feedback will be well appreciated.

Thanks!

**Edit: Important note I forgot to mention is I'm using a spawn command via a script to execute the ssh instruction**

Comment: Try single instead of double backslashes? Could be that the double quotes already provide escapism. Also, are there any spaces in the path?

Comment: In cases like this, you need to know the full sequence of parsing (and escape/quote processing/removal) the command is going to go through, and and work backward through it. Start with the remote filename, then add quotes/escapes as needed for CMD's parsing, then take that and add quotes/escapes for the local shell (*if* it's being processed by a local shell), then take that and add quotes/escapes as needed by whatever language you're running the spawn from (if that's the correct sequence).

Comment: Please show how you're issuing this from the `spawn` command. There may be an extra level of quote and escape processing. It would probably be better to put the command into a shell script, and then spawn that, rather than spawning ssh directly.

Comment: The [Windows command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands) __DEL__ does not have an option `-f`. There is interpreted for that reason `-f` as file to delete in addition to the second file name `F:\some\path\in\remote\1.computer\1.filename.txt`. Yes, it is possible to specify multiple files to delete with command __DEL__. Try `ssh user@host 'del /A /F "F:\some\path\in\remote\1.computer\1.filename.txt"'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is related to backslashes. You need to escape a backslash with another one, but you need four backslashes at the first position so it will be evaluated as two backslashes:

```
ssh user@host "del -f F:\\\\some\\path\\in\\remote\\1.computer\\1.filename.txt"
```

Comment: Thanks! this helped and worked, only thing is I had to use the four backlashes for all:

ssh user@host "del -f F:\\\\some\\\\path\\\\in\\\\remote\\\\1.computer\\\\1.filename.txt"